# Edit Custom UserIdentity objects (in database)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am in the middle of making my first ASP.NET Core application using ASP.NET Identity. I have now managed to make a custom `IdentityUser` class (named `ApplicationUser`), which extends from the standard IdentityUser class shipped in the scaffolded Identity package. `ApplicationUser` now has some extra fields (Address, Status, FirstName, LastName), and my application and database recognizes both in the desired way, and new users are correctly added to the database when using the Register form. Naturally, I have replaced the usage of `IdentityUser` with `ApplicationUser`, and customized

> Register.cshtml

and

> Register.cshtml.cs

, so that the extra fields are in use.
My issue is now, that I feel like I am unware of how one is supposed to update a user object (in the database) in the "natural sense". The default `UserManager` seems to be designed for updating instances of the default `IdentityUser`, but not classes that inherit from `IdentityUser`. And it seems that `UserManager` by default handles issues like asynchronous operations, and the only (by default) available method that I suspect to be of any use is `#UpdateAsync` in `UserManager`.
What can I do?

Comment: Hi @Birdie,Did my answer help you resolve your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working demo about how to update the ApplicationUser:

Model:

```
public class ApplicationUser:IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model ApplicationUser
<form asp-action="UpdateUser">
    <div>
        <label asp-for="Email"></label>
        <input asp-for="Email" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label asp-for="FirstName"></label>
        <input asp-for="FirstName" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label asp-for="LastName"></label>
        <input asp-for="LastName" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="update" />
</form>
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    public HomeController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }
    
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult UpdateUser(ApplicationUser applicationUser)
    {
        var user = _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(applicationUser.Email).Result;
        //modify the data...
        user.FirstName = applicationUser.FirstName;
        user.LastName = applicationUser.LastName;
        var result = _userManager.UpdateAsync(user).Result;
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

ApplicationDbContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(
            Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddRazorPages();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`UserManager` works with generic types that inherit from `IdentityUser`, which you have done. So just Inject `UserManager<ApplicationUser>` rather than `UserManager<IdentityUser>` into where you need it (e.g. Register.cshtml.cs) and use that to operate on your users.